# ElasticsSearch query string query

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I have a document that indexed as CAT AND DOG without lowercase version. When I use QueryStringQuery, it recognizes "AND" as its feature. Is there any way to use this query with documetns like that with AND,OR keyword without lowercase them?

In whitespace tokenizer `CAT AND DOG` will be  CAT,AND,DOG.

When I run the query string query, they will be parsed separately and since AND is alone in query, it will give an error.

Comment: If you query with the double quotes, then ES does an exact match: Try `"CAT AND DOG"`

Comment: My document is CAT AND DOG. I wanted to highlight that is why I put it in quotes

Comment: Can you show your document and mapping?

Comment: If you run this :  `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=whitespace&pretty=true' -d 'CAT AND DOG' -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' ` , You will see CAT,AND,DOG are indexed separately. So when I call query string query, CAT AND DOG will be parsed separately and it will give the error because AND is written alone. I can fix this in code. However, Is there anyway to do it without code?